# mysql - between two times in one day

Tags: mysql, sql

**MySQL rows:**

```
id  work_time_from  work_time_to
1   12:30           23:00
2   14:00           18:00
```

**input data:**

```
$curTime = 13:15
```

**Problem:**

I have to fetch all rows corresponding condition **work_time_from** < $curTime < **work_time_to**

**My request is:**

```
SELECT * FROM companies WHERE work_time_from < "13:15" AND work_time_to > "13:15"
```

It doesn't work i think because of work_time_from, work_time_to `varchar` type.

Comment: Why doesn't it work with `varchar`? Make sure you have leading `0` on times before `10:00`.

Comment: It works correctly here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84045d/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `STR_TO_DATE` to convert your fields and then `BETWEEN` to compare.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CURTIME(),'%h:%i') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(work_time_from,'%h:%i') AND STR_TO_DATE(work_time_to,'%h:%i')
```

Comment: thank you, some correction: `SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE STR_TO_DATE($curTime, '%H;%i') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(work_time_from ,'%H:%i') AND STR_TO_DATE(work_time_to,'%H:%i')`

Comment: @Michael i have udpated my answer